# Как получить ширину layout при инициализации?

Tags: android

getViewTreeObserver() не подходит так как его callback возвращается в конце всех шагов инициализации(onCreate, onResume...)

onMeasure - не понял как работает, кажется надо переопределять layout, это мне не надо

view.getVWidth() - возвращает 0

Comment: При инициализации чего?

Comment: @post_zeew  При инициализации layout

Comment: **Во время** инициализации `layout` его размеры вероятнее всего будут нулевые. Было бы неплохо, если бы Вы описали чего конкретно Вы хотите добиться.

Comment: @post_zeew написал _выбиралку_ фоток. Она является фрагментом, можно встраивать в активити. Фрагмент состоит из 8 `ImageView` (зависит от настроек) внутри `GridLayout`, где будут выбранные фото. Размер `ImageView` нужно инициализировать в зависимости от ширины родительского layout, это нужно чтобы `ImageView` выглядели соразмерно экрану